# What is the difference between "ultrasound" and "ultrasonic"?

Tags: difference

It seems to me that both words are used interchangeably. The Wikipedia article for "ultrasound" does not introduce the word "ultrasonic", but just uses it in the introduction as if it was totally clear to the reader that "ultrasonic" is the adjective and adverb to "ultrasound".

Is that the case and is it the only distinction between the words?

Comment: "Ultrasonic" is the adjective form of ultrasound. In fact, Oxford uses "ultrasonic" to define "ultrasound": "***noun** sound or other vibrations having an ultrasonic frequency...*" The term "ultrasound", on its own, is commonly used to refer to medical ultrasonic imaging and to medical ultrasound images, while "ultrasonic" is not used that way.